# Jetty 8.1 flooding the log file with "Dispatched Failed" messages

Tags: jetty, embedded-jetty

We are using Jetty 8.1 as an embedded HTTP server. Under overload conditions the server sometimes starts flooding the log file with these messages:

```
warn: java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException
warn: Dispatched Failed! SCEP@76107610{l(...)<->r(...),d=false,open=true,ishut=false,oshut=false,rb=false,wb=false,w=true,i=1r}...
```

The same message is repeated thousands of times, and the amount of logging appears to slow down the whole system. The messages itself are fine, our request handler ist just to slow to process the requests in time. But the huge number of repeated messages makes things actually worse and makes it more difficult for the system to recover from the overload.

So, my question is: is this a normal behaviour, or are we doing something wrong? 
Here is how we set up the server:

```java
Server server = new Server();
SelectChannelConnector connector = new SelectChannelConnector();
connector.setAcceptQueueSize( 10 );
server.setConnectors( new Connector[]{ connector } );
server.setThreadPool( new ExecutorThreadPool( 32, 32, 60, TimeUnit.SECONDS,
                                              new ArrayBlockingQueue<Runnable>( 10 )));
```

Answer (score 0):

The [SelectChannelEndPoint is the origin of this log](http://git.eclipse.org/c/jetty/org.eclipse.jetty.project.git/tree/jetty-io/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/io/nio/SelectChannelEndPoint.java?id=jetty-8.1.10.v20130312#n225) message.

To not see it, just set your named logger of `org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint` to LEVEL=OFF.

Now as for why you see it, that is more interesting to the developers of Jetty.  Can you detail what specific version of Jetty you are using and also what specific JVM you are using?

Comment: We are using Jetty 8.1.10.v20130312 with Java 1.6.0. The problem has been seen with 1.6.0_22, 1.6.0_44 (Oracle) and J9VM 2.4 (IBM).

Comment: I have meed this problem too. Have u solved this problem? Any help will be thankful.