# Prometheus - Dispatched Failed

Tags: jetty, prometheus

I just want to use prometheus agent to monitor some parameters.
Application is launched with agent

```
-javaagent:lib/boot/jmx_prometheus_javaagent-0.9.jar=$PROMETHEUS_PORT:etc/jmx.prometheus.yaml
```

but unfortunately I get a lot of warnings like this

> 2017-05-09 16:39:11.585:WARN:ipjsoeji.nio:Dispatched Failed!
>   SCEP@24e5b398{l(/172.20.26.126:55958)<->r(/172.20.26.100:9255),d=false,open=true,ishut=false,oshut=false,rb=false,wb=false,w=true,i=1r}-{AsyncHttpConnection@6471d314,g=HttpGenerator{s=0,h=-1,b=-1,c=-1},p=HttpParser{s=-14,l=0,c=0},r=0}
>   to
>   io.prometheus.jmx.shaded.org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector$ConnectorSelectorManager@6d2459c4

It's some kind of flood of logs. In few seconds log file reaches over 1GB size.

I've read threads about this issue (like [Jetty 8.1 flooding the log file with "Dispatched Failed" messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16592537/jetty-8-1-flooding-the-log-file-with-dispatched-failed-messages)) but it does not solve my problem.

Does anyone meet the same issue and know why this problem occures and how to fix it?

Comment: Hey, did you find a way to solve this?

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't.

Comment: I upgraded the agent to version 0.10, and it works fine.
Did you try it? Or only 0.9

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion but unfortunately I don't use prometheus anymore. Probably new version doesn't have this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like https://github.com/prometheus/jmx_exporter/issues/122, assuming you have many cores.